# Problems setting up zephyr for vs code

Tags: arm, zephyr-rtos

I have been facing issues while setting up vs code for zephyr applications. I want to be able to build, flash and debug my projects. But I'm getting an error that says zephyr/kernel.h is not existing. I have updated the include path to the directory where the header is but I am still getting errors. Has anyone faces similar issues, and how to fix them?

I have updated the compiler path, and the include path.